# What is the best way to reliably mount a USB drive?

Tags: raspbmc, hard-drive

I've installed raspbmc, but from what I've seen it's based on raspbian, so this might go for raspbian too.

I've connected a USB hard-drive. *Most* of the time, it will be automatically mounted on `/media/usb0`, to which `/media/usb` is a symlink.

My problem is in that *most*. What is the best way to have the drive mounted at boot at the same mountpoint?

I did some looking around. Can I use `/dev/disk/by-label` in `/etc/fstab` or will that clash with the automatic mounting, which sometimes doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Chris. Mount by label or uuid should work fine, however it means it will only mount at boot. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want it to at least be mounted at boot. Right now sometimes it won't get mounted. And reconnecting it might mount it at /media/usb1, invalidating all media paths stored in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `/dev/disk/by-id` without any issues, so I suggest you use that.

Comment: This is the best way. These links are updated by `udev` upon detecting devices.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: In 2021, you would typically use the `PARTUUID` from `$ blkid /dev/sdx`. Then the `/etc/fstab` line would start with `PARTUUID=xxxxxxxx-yy`.

Answer (score 1):

On Raspbian, automount no longer mounts USB drives as `/media/usbx` by default since at least 4 years now, probably more. You get them mounted as `/media/user/disk_label` now, which is also reliable, unless you have a habit of giving the same label to several disks. If you don't label your disks, you'll get `/media/user/UUID`, which is also reliable, but not really user-friendly.

If you have more than 1 disk, configuring automount will save you time and frustration compared to manually editing `/etc/fstab` every time.